# Why is there a need of the 2 following methods in NumberFormat?

Tags: java, parsing, number-formatting

I see that [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) has two methods very similar:

**1)**

```
abstract Number     parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition)
```

> Returns a Long if possible (e.g., within the range [Long.MIN_VALUE,
>   Long.MAX_VALUE] and with no decimals), otherwise a Double.

**2)**

```
Object  parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos)
```

> Parses text from a string to produce a Number.

In presence of `parse(s,ParseIndex)` what would be the need of `parseObject(..)` which needs to be cast to the desired output? 
I am aware that the first method throws `ParseException` and the latter does not.
Just wondering why the need of these 2 very similar methods.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most commonly heard complaints about the JDK is why `Integer.parseInt` and similar methods cannot be used to validate the string without involving the expensive mechanism of exceptions. `NumberFormat` seems to have answered that complaint by providing a method which can signal failure by returning `null`.

Comment: It's funny that the same method of the child class DecimalFormat parse(String, ParsePosition) does not throw ParseException.

Comment: +1 For a great answer. Although I personally did not ask the question you did a great job of explaining it in a way that made me think why "I" would want to use it.

Comment: @Rollerball Note that there are `parse(String,ParsePosition)`, `parse(String)`, and `parseObject(String,ParsePosition)`, all in the `NumberFormat` class. Those methods which accept a `ParsePosition` do not throw, they use this object to signal the location of parse error.